# Make a style rule that tests for a child having an attribute with a given property

Tags: qgis, style, qfield, rule-based

In QGIS/QField, I have a feature (plants) with child features, which are dated observations of the plant, and I would like to make the appearance (color or shape) of the feature depend on whether there is an observation after some given date, say, July 1 2022 (to make it easy to see whether the plant has resprouted this year).  But I haven't managed to work out what the syntax for that would be, or find an example somewhere.

Here are the parent's fields:
[image]

and here the child's:

[image]

In terms of implementation, there might be too much looping (for each plant, for each observation, is it later than date X, return yes when one is found, no when all are inspected and none has been found), but there isn't that much data.

Comment: oops, QGis/QField; question edited!

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this is what you are aiming for. Let me know if I have misunderstood your data structure.

I have two tables, one `plants_parent` and the other `plants_child`. `plants_parent` has 3 records which are the plant locations. `plants_child` is a no-geometry table containing observations of those plants on different dates.

###### Parent layer

[image]

###### Child layer

[image]

###### Relation

In the Project -> Properties, I set a many-to-one relation using a `plant_id` column in the child, related to the `fid` in the parent. The relation is named `plants_relation`.

###### Expression

Using the following expression as a rule-based symbology, it is possible to see which plants have been observed after 2022-07-01.

There are several nested functions, the first 3 comments should be read bottom to top to make sense.

```
array_length(                              -- check if the array has any elements after filtering
    array_filter(                          -- filter the array for dates after 2022-07-01
        relation_aggregate(                -- aggregate all dates (per parent plant) into an array
            'plants_relation',              -- name of the relation in the project properties
            'array_agg',                 
            date_seen                      -- the field values to aggregate
        ), 
        @element > make_date(2022, 7, 1)   -- @element is the current array element being evaluated
    )
) > 0                                      -- rule returns true when there are dates remaining after filtering
```

###### Result

[image]

*Note: labels for visualisation were created using the same expression inside a `case` statement.*

Comment: This worked, and performed well on QField on the phone as well!  Thanks!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 3):

I'd try tackle this would be by using rule based symbology if I understand what you're asking.

**Data**

[image: Data]

**Expressions**

[image: Expressions]

**Outcome**

[image: Outcome]

Comment: It's a many-to-one relation, as clarified above.  I have succeeded in getting different displays with a rule-based symbology that just checks that a 'seen' attribute isn't NULL, and maybe that's good enough, but fully automatic would be better if practical.